# Switched outlet has "open neutral" when switch is off, and shows "wired correctly" when switch is on

Tags: switch, neutral

Switched outlet has "open neutral" when switch is off, and shows "wired correctly" when switch is on. All other outlets in the room show "wired correctly" so the only thing upstream is the switch, and who knows what is upstream from that. The only reason I noticed this, is because I replaced a regular switch with a rocker switch that has a tiny locator light built-in that wasn't illuminating. So now I'm trying to figure out whats going on. Thoughts?

I've also realized that with the outlet tester plugged in, the locator light on the switch illuminates.. when I remove the outlet tester, no more locator light

[image: paddle switch with locator light]

Comment: In fact, if the illuminated switch is designed based on "leak current through the regular load", it won't light up when used with a receptacle rather than a hard-wired light, plus may not work *properly* if used with an LED or fluorescent light. Too many unknowns until we get pictures and/or switch details.

Comment: What country? Those aren't the expected colors for the US...

Comment: Chicago suburbs

Comment: The colors look *strange*. That *may* just be the lighting. Can you please tell us what colors you consider each of the wires - specifically: wires in going into switch (two colors, what are they?), wires going into receptacle (two colors, what are they?), bundle of wires in back of switch box (one color, what is it?)

Comment: Also, very important, **model # of new switch**?

Comment: OK, that's individual wires in conduit. That's good, changing wrong wires is easy.  Why are there 2 white wires on th receptacle but only 1 hot wire?  Is the receptacle split?  Do the 2 white wires go off into different conduit pipes back there? Is there another hot wire connecting the two pipes?

Comment: Outlet has 1 red wire to brass and 2 white wires that are actually the same wire with a loop around the silver screw.... then my switch has red on top and a looped gray wire attached to it.... 3 white wires in the back

Comment: Model number of the switch is TM870WSLCC10 its a Legrand Radiant paddle switch with locator light from Menards.

Comment: I just added another photo.. the 2 white wires do go into 2 different conduit pipes. Also noticed a gray loop, same color as conntected to my switch, going from 1 pipe to the other.

Comment: I think you answered below Harper's answer regarding the receptacle. But what about the *switch* - was it screwed into the box when you tested it? I have a hunch (documentation isn't clear) that this switch relies on ground to complete the circuit for the indicator light, so with metal box/no ground wire it will only work when screwed into the box.

Comment: Everything was screwed down and mounted, faceplate included..

Answer (score 3):

Edit:   Herp a derp. I missed the obvious. There is nothing wrong here.  Just a testing artifact.

### The lighted switch *will not work* unless you have a lamp plugged into the socket, and turned on.

That is the nature of lighted switches which wire up with 2 wires (well, 2 wire *terminals, the double blue is simply hot going onward).  This is also true of any motion sensor, powered switch and you're not allowed to put a dimmer on a receptacle. That is working as intended and there is nothing wrong with the hardware.

Why is it that way?  Because with only 2 wires to the switch (well 2 terminals), the two mandatory wires to *any* switch are "always-hot" and "switched-hot" to the lamp.  The only way it can access power is to "leak" some current through the lamp. Note this also depends on having a lamp plugged in, turned on, and which doesn't have a problem with leakage current.  Edison's old indcandescent bulbs were very tolerant of that; LEDs *vary*.

Why don't the device just grab neutral and power itself between always-hot (which it has)  and neutral?  Because they can't count on neutral being present in the box.  Half the switches in America are wired with an old-style "switch loops".  It would be neat if they'd offer "powers off the neutral" versions of all these things, but that's bad business on a DIY product. DIYers will buy before they check, and then return the product. Home Depot and Amazon make manufacturers eat returns.

### So what's up with the 3-light tester?

Why does the right yellow light up but not the center yellow when the switch is off?  Well, that's that leakage current being seen by the tester.  Probably.  There's not enough leakage current to light both neon lights, and the end yellow is lighting preferentially either due to manufacturing variances, or a resistor on that neon bulb to improve reliablity.

I sure can't see anything wrong with the wiring.  The "gray" wire is in fact light blue (Robins egg blue) and that is a legal hot color.  I am personally miffed that we have 8 hot colors and only 2 neutral colors, and *would like to see* Robins Egg Blue (Europe's neutral color) become our 3rd, but that is not how the <del>world</del> continent works.

---

---

Original answer:

> Switched outlet has "open neutral" when switch is off, and shows "wired correctly" when switch is on.

The magic 8-ball tester is probably telling the truth for once. If the switch was properly wired, the tester would not light *at all* since the hot wire would be interrupted by the switch.  So in this case, most likely, the switch was incorrectly installed, such that it switches neutral instead of switching hot.   I gather this was the prior nitwit's work and you just reused the same wires.

> The only reason I noticed this, is because I replaced a regular switch with a rocker switch that has a tiny locator light built-in that wasn't illuminating.

Well, if the switch does not have a neutral wire, then the little lamp is not going to illuminate unless a lamp is plugged into that socket and switched on.  So that's your problem there.

If the switch *does* have a neutral wire that it uses to power the little lamp, then it's not working because of the previously mentioned mistake wiring the switch to interrupt neutral. Switches are supposed to be wired between always-hot and switched-hot, giving the switch access to both of those.  Add neutral and now it has power to run its on-the-switch loads.   If such a switch is placed in a "switched neutral" configuration, then it has access to always-neutral, switched-neutral and always-neutral a second time.  That's not helpful lol.

Comment: What I'm confused about is the white wires going to the outlet aren't connected to the switch. Instead a gray wire is connected to the switch. I supposed that's my open neutral, but how do I solve it?

Comment: @Don wait. When you use your tester on this thing... is it mounted on the junction box or flapping loosey goosey in the wind as in the photos?  Because if it isn't screwed down it doesn't have any grounds and only the center yellow light will have any meaning at all.

Comment: It was screwed to the box fully mounted when I tested it

Comment: @Don -- those "gray" wires are really discolored white wires -- the switch is clearly switching neutral instead of hot from the photos you posted

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I disagree that they're discolored white wires. They are very clearly gray and different from the white wires... but what do I do to correct the wiring? The switch has red and gray (with white bundled in the box), and the outlet has red and white (with a gray looping from one conduit pipe to another as seen in the last photo)...

Comment: Problem is that gray is *also* supposed to be neutral. And in conduit (e.g., Chicago-land) you can't reuse a neutral color for something else. Which means either gray is *not* neutral and there is a small problem somewhere, or gray *is* really a neutral color and all kinds of things were done wrong.

Comment: @Don Thanks for looking for that extra wire. That explains the neutrals doing what they're doing.  I am satisfied the "gray" wire is actually light blue, which is a legit hot color.  In that light, the wiring looks entirely proper, and the 3-light tester is just *wrong, as usual*.  There is nothing wrong with this setup, except for you being unfamiliar with how these products, um, work.

Comment: Just saw the latest edit. That was my original hunch, and it should explain the magic 8-ball results. **However**, the switch is a modern switch, uses an LED itself, and makes no indication of any restrictions regarding what it switches. I would expect something like this to be a bit problematic with LED lighting. I *suspect* that it may use ground for power, as it seems to require ground. Or at least, the wiring diagram clearly shows ground but on the other hand it doesn't make a big deal about "must have ground". So I can't say for sure - the instructions are less detailed than I'd like.

Comment: @manassehkatz UL won't let you leak more than 0.5mA  (60mW) to ground. Are LEDs efficient enough for 60mW to light a switch? Couldn't say.

Comment: ~ 100 lumens per watt (quick search) so 60 mW = ~ 6 Lumens. A typical (old) standard incandescent night light bulb is 15 lumens. Is 40% of a standard night light enough for a lighted switch? I think it is!

Comment: @manassehkatz one way to easily find out (for OP): if the switch is floating free of the junction box it won't be grounded.

Comment: Which is why I asked above whether it was tested in the box or out.

Comment: So the wiring is correct and no action is needed? I just need something plugged into the outlet for the locator light to illuminate. I appreciate everybody's help! Did you want me to test something with the switch floating free of the box? Just for ships and giggles?

Comment: From [the new purple question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/267953/trying-to-get-switch-to-control-only-half-the-outlet), *dim power to light fixture when switch is off, and full power when switch is on* so that pretty much confirms it is "leak through load" and not "use ground". I just don't get how the switch companies think people will go for "dim when off".

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact yeah it's more than just dim, it's at least 50% on

Comment: @Don All of these "leak current through the bulb" type devices are designed for incandescent lights.  So use an incandescent light fixture to establish whether it's installed correctly or not.  Then figure out the LED issue.