# Trying to get switch to control only half the outlet

Tags: switch

Ok new bedroom, new question..

I have this legrand radiant paddle switch with locator light giving me another headache. Model# TM870WSLCC10

The switch has 1 red wire, 1 robins egg blue wire, and a white wire behind it in the box.

The outlet has 1 red wire, 3 white wires, and in the back of the box 2 blue + 1 black together in a wirenut.

I broke the tab off of the outlet on the brass side. No power to bottom outlet, and the top outlet gives dim power to light fixture when switch is off, and full power when switch is on.

Before breaking the tab off, the switch controlled both outlets without any issues.

I'm just trying to make one side switched and 1 side hot. My guess is this switch with the locator light built-in is causing the issue but I'm no electrician I have no idea.

You guys are the best and I appreciate your help!

Photos below:
[image: outlet and switch]

Comment: You should not have broken the tab on the neutral side of the outlets. You should only have broken the tab on the hot side, and connected a pigtail from the wire nut over to the hot side.

Answer (score 2):

Add a short wire (black or blue or any other color except white, gray or green) to the wire nut (might need a new or larger wire nut) that has black and blue wires. Connect it to the bottom brass side screw.

Comment: That would make the other outlet hot all the time, but would it solve the issue of having the light fixture stay dimly lit even when switched off?

Comment: No. That's because of how the switch gets power for the indicator light.